# Android SU Command To Replace an Image File in System Apk?

Tags: java, android, shell, root, busybox

I want to change the image file in an Installed apk that's not the apk icon file. I got a script which does the same I am looking to change the icon without to boot into recovery ... Please help .... Here is the script I found...

```
#!/tmp/busybox sh

/tmp/apkreplacer /system/app/Browser.apk res/drawable-ldpi/original_image.png /sdcard/new_image.png >> /sdcard/test.log 2>&1

busybox chmod 644 /system/app/*;
busybox chown root.root /system/app/*;
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: how can I use this as a root command from my app.... this execute in recovery.

Comment: Have you tried anything to help yourself? you may start from here http://su.chainfire.eu/